# Symfony 2.6 restrict url by host but allow a specific IP to access it

Tags: access-control, symfony-2.6

I am trying to allow a specific IP to access a restricted path defined in security.yml with no success.

I have these 2 lines in my security.yml:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,  ip: "127.0.0.1" }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, host: "test.loc" }
```

However, I am redirected to the login page when I try to access the project on my local.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're running afoul of Chrome's aggressive 301 redirect caching.  See a discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects).  Try in another browser such as Firefox.

The problem should go away if you clear Chrome's browsing data.  You can also pop in to incognito mode to test.